# icons should always have the same distance from the border box

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to do a team overview for a company. The data such as name, job title and information are retrieved from the database. The information is of different length and therefore the icons are not on one line

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get a uniform distance for the icons from the bottom of the borderbox?

HTML:  (It's about the div called testusus)

```
            @foreach ($employees as $employee)
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="float-box float-box-no-border-white about-team text-center tes">
                        <div class="hvrbox">
                            <a href="{{ action('WorkerController@show', $employee) }}"><img
                                        src="{{ $employee->profile_picture_url }}" class="img-team">
                                <div class="hvrbox-layer_top">
                                    <div class="hvrbox-text">Erfahre mehr über mich</div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <h3>{{ $employee->first_name }} {{ $employee->last_name }}<br>
                            <hr class="hr-team">
                            <small>{{ $employee->position }}</small>
                        </h3>

                        <p class="p-text">{{ $employee->main_info }}</p>
                    </div>
                    

                    <div class="testusus">
                        <a href="mailto:{{ $employee->email_company }}"><i
                                    class="icon-envelope icon-share-small"></i></a>
                        @isset($employee->linkedin)
                            <a href="{{ $employee->linkedin }}" target="_blank"><i
                                        class="icon-linkedin icon-share-small"></i></a>
                        @endisset
                    </div>


                </div>
            @endforeach
```

CSS:

```
.testusus {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can give the parent-element `position: relative;` and the icons a `position: fixed;` and a `bottom` of maybe `10px` (`bottom: 10px;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your boxes `flex` and then use `margin-top: auto;` on the bottom parts:

```css
#container { display: flex; }

.box {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

    <div class="bottom">
      Bottom
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    <div class="bottom">
      Bottom
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```